# How to get HTML contents including parent?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand how to get the HTML contents including the parent selector. I know that the following will get me the HTML contents:

```
$obj.html();
```

(where $obj is a reference to my DOM object)

But what if I want the HTML contents including the parent selector? For example, let's say I have this code:

```
<div id="sample" class="something">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If I do:

```
$('#sample').html();
```

...I will get:

```
<div class="inner"></div>
```

But what I really want retuned is this:

```
<div id="sample" class="something">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not standard - this works pretty much [everywhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML#Browser_compatibility).

Use [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML)

```
var el = $obj[0]; // get the HTML element from the jQuery object
el.outerHTML; // the HTML including the outside bits
```

( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tK4x/) )

Comment: Sounds good to me - when you say it's no standardm is it reliable?

Comment: @Andrew I can't really say. Knowing the people involved in the decision process - I think it might get standardized eventually, and it certainly won't be removed from browsers. In practice - it's not going anywhere any time soon - the problem is the unspecified behavior in edge cases across browsers, but I'm yet to run into any edge cases myself.

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't completely standardized just yet, `Element.outerHTML` works in most browsers.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m52Zx/2/)

```
document.querySelector('#sample').outerHTML;
```

[Polyfills are available](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/1044128) is earlier browser support is desired:

#### References

- [W3C spec outerHTML](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/apis-in-html-documents.html#outerhtml)
- [WHATWG spec outerHTML](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#outerhtml)

Comment: +1 for the references. I forgot to add those :) It seems like it (outerHTML) progressed quite a bit since last I checked.